# Registering HSQLDB driver with class.ForName

Tags: java, junit4, hsqldb

I'm having a weird problem with NetBeans 5.5.1. I'm creating a test class for one of my classes. The method I'm testing gets its own connection from a method called getConnection, which is as follows:

```
//This method was mainly done for an HSQLDB connection
public static Connection getConnection(String connectionString,String databaseDriver, String user, String pass) throws Exception
{
    Connection conn = null;
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("Registering database driver "+databaseDriver);
        Class.forName(databaseDriver);
        System.out.println("Successfully registered database driver "+databaseDriver);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user",user);
        props.setProperty("password",pass);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, props);
    } 
       catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
       {
        System.out.println("Reached catch block getConnection()");
        throw new Exception ("Unable to create connection to database", ex);
    }

    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Reached catch block getConnection()");
        throw new Exception ("Unable to create connection to database", ex);
    }

        return new DatabaseConnection(conn).getConnection();

}
```

The database driver I'm using is HSQLDB. 
After running my test method, the only log statement printed to my output is 
**Registering database driver org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver**

My expected result is:
**Registering database driver org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver** 
**Successfully registered database driver org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver**

When I deliberately use a wrong database driver, I can clearly see an exception being thrown, which means that the above driver I'm using is working, and that it can be found in my classPath.

So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Does the method return successfully, or is `Class.forName` maybe throwing an `Error` (as opposed to an `Exception`)?

Comment: No, the method just ends there. And I don't think that any Exceptions are being thrown since none of my catch blocks are reached.

Comment: That's why I suggested that it might be an `Error` (which is a subclass of `Throwable` but _not_ of `Exception`).  If you change the `catch(Exception ex)` to `catch(Throwable ex)` then you'll be able to see if this is indeed the case.

Comment: Man this has helped me figure out the problem! Apparently HSQLDB 2.2.9 does not work with JDK5, so I had to replace it with HSQLDB 2.2.8. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by "Ian Roberts", when catching exceptions as a Throwable, I realized that the Class.ForName was complaining about a bad class number (This happens when you're trying to compile with a JDK that's older than one of your libraries). Changing HSQLDB from version 2.2.9 to 2.2.8.jdk5 fixed the problem.

Comment: There is a JDK5 version of HSQLDB 2.2.9 on Maven https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.2.9/